# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file' for one database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'file'.

Query looks like this:

```
UPDATE t 
SET name = s.[Value] 
FROM [dbo].[file] t 
JOIN [dbo].[#TempTable] s ON t.[name] = s.[Key]
```

Temp table created:

```
CREATE TABLE [#TempTable] ([Key] varchar(500), [Value] varchar(500))
```

Same thing in code:

```
 var commandText = "UPDATE t " +
 $"SET [{column.ColumnName}] = s.[{valueColumn.ColumnName}] " +
 $"FROM {table.FullTableName} t " +
 $"JOIN {mappingsTable.FullTableName} s ON t.[{column.ColumnName}] = s.[{keyColumn.ColumnName}] ";
```

And executed:

```
using (var command = CreateCommand(connection, transaction))
{
    command.CommandText = commandText;
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This issue occurs only in 1 database. Three other databases on different/same servers are ok.

What can it be?

UPD

If I rename table to [dbo].[file1] - everything works.

Comment: Assuming `{table.FullTableName}` is not wrapped in `[ ]` like you state. If it was, I cannot imagine you would get a complaint about a keyword of `file`. I see you are explicitly putting brackets around the columns, perhaps you just need to do the same to table unless you are expecting to already be wrapped from the property.

Comment: FullName = [schema].[TableName] and will result in [dbo].[file] so it's wrapped

Comment: Just to satisfy us - can you print out the value of `commandText` that's been generated, rather than having us guess at the contents of multiple variables that you've not even shown us being set.

Comment: This query is in the question itself: 

Query looks like this:
UPDATE t 
SET name = s.[Value] 
FROM [dbo].[file] t 
JOIN [dbo].[#TempTable] s ON t.[name] = s.[Key]

Comment: So, are you claiming that that's the exact value that the `commandText` variable contained at the point at which the `SqlException` was thrown, and you've verified this by printing it out whilst debugging?

Comment: Yes, this exact query which failed. When I run it in management studio - everything is ok. When I run this query from app on my local machine with same table - everything is okey. When I run this query on virtual machine on this particular database - it fails. It works though on different db on save virtual machine. Creating script for table is same.